# Remove parts of a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array being created from a .csv file, the resulting array has data that I have no use for so I would like to cleanup the array before proceeding.

```
array (size=45)
  0 => 
    array (size=63)
      '﻿"Unique ID"' => string '3585370' (length=7)
      'Source ID' => string '242' (length=3)
      'Source Date' => string '20/9/18 12:08:22 AM' (length=19)
      'Email' => string 'email@email.com' (length=3)
```

How can I remove "Source Date" and "Source ID" from the array of each record?

Comment: With `unset` function?

Comment: I'd be more worried about array keys with quotes in them - gets confusing at times.

Comment: I would suggest **NOT adding irrelevant data** from the CSV file to your array in the first place!

Comment: `unset($array[$key])` or `unset($array[$i])` where `$i` is the position the array.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Or [even this](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)

Comment: @RiggsFolly new favourite gif xD

Comment: You could also use ```array_map``` with ```unset```. The question was closed so I can't post an example without bloating this comment, but here is a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Bhm2iHwv)